# AngularJS photo/file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Uploading file and photo seems to be working fine on other browsers apart from FF. It seems to be its failing somewhere in the form.append but I don't get why its working on Chrome and IE but not FF.

Can someone shed a light on this one please.

controller:

```
$scope.uploadProfilePhoto = function() {
            $timeout(function(){
                var form = new FormData();
                form.append("fileName", vm.profilePhoto.fileName);
                form.append('file', vm.profilePhoto.file);
                ProfileService.uploadProfilePicture(form)
                    .then(function(response){
                        vm.ProfilePictureUrl = api.getQualifiedUrl('image/' + response.data.ImageId);
                    })
            });
        }
```

Input:

```
<label for="profilePhoto" class="photo-upd" >
  <img data-ng-src="{{vm.ProfilePictureUrl}}" id="profile-picture_image" alt="Candidate profile photo" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadProfilePhoto(this)" class="img-responsive">                        
  <span><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload Photo</span>
</label>
<input id="profilePhoto" type="file" name="profilePhoto" valid-file data-oh-file fileread="vm.profilePhoto.file" filename="vm.profilePhoto.fileName" class="hidden"onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadProfilePhoto(this)">
```

Error:

```
vm.profilePhoto is undefined
Profile/$scope.uploadProfilePhoto/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just notice that the `vm` object must be the `self` or `this` of the object/controller.

And you need to declare the `vm.profilePhoto` object as well:

> ```
> var vm = this;
> vm.profilePhoto = {};
> ```

#### JS:

example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/alvarojoao/v9rfn301/

```
var app = angular.module("turingApp", []);

app.controller("turingController", ["$scope","$timeout", function($scope,$timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.profilePhoto = {};

  $scope.uploadProfilePhoto = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      var form = new FormData();
      form.append("fileName", vm.profilePhoto.fileName);
      form.append('file', vm.profilePhoto.file);
      ProfileService.uploadProfilePicture(form)
        .then(function(response) {
          vm.ProfilePictureUrl = api.getQualifiedUrl('image/' + response.data.ImageId);
        })
    });
  };

}]);
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the answer. I put an empty vm.profilePhoto and seems to work fine but will do further debugging.

Comment: Seems to be that it has to wait for the file to be uploaded completely before the onchange apply, is there a way to do it without timeout delay? Putting a delay seems to work okay but not sure if that's a best way.

Comment: Yep I will post an example without delay. Give me 30 min. .

Comment: Reason there's a delay is because there is an async call for the file to upload therefore it has to wait, so what's the best func/service to use other than $timeout and $interval or is there any other way to wait for the async?

Comment: You can add a callback function or just use .then if you are using $http

Comment: use .then instead of $timeout?

Comment: Yep, just like you did with `ProfileService` you add this function before the rest of the function execution; and Then add all the rest inside. e.g: `FirstCall.then( function(response){ 
      var form = new FormData();
      form.append("fileName", vm.profilePhoto.fileName); 
       ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using $scope.vm In the upload function?

Comment: This should be a comment than an answer, nope I replaced $scope as vm. It seems to work okay as Im getting the fileName and path when I run it on FF debugger.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a high enough rep to comment. If vm is scope why are you using both?. Also if vm is scope you shouldn't have vm in the html